# How to store More than 5MB data in a Web Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage, web-storage

I know that local and session storage capacity is `5MB` and cookie has `4MB`,

If I want to store More than 5MB data in web storage ONLY then what is the alternate solution for this?

Comment: What are you planing to store?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat - It can be any thing, key, value pairs

Comment: Reason I ask is that 5mb is pretty a lot :) And if you need store more maybe its not right, you would need to store more on server side

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of the options would be to IndexedDb. Which also has some limitation and they depends on users [storage configuration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria#Storage_limits)

You can check [supported browsers here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)

Answer (score 1):

One solution that is provided by the browser is [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

If the accessibility may be an issue, you might want to check the [caniuse page](https://caniuse.com/#search=indexdb) to see what browsers are supported.

I think this is what is used by [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) in the background. But you can use it with [other backends like localStorage or memory](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser). So it may be good if you are not sure of the quantity of data first, but want to preserve the same API. Also PouchDB can sync with non browser database which is pretty cool for web applications that need to work offline.